# Drift velocity of charges in current

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

In an electric curcuit, charges (electrons e.g.) move randomly around very, very fast. When a current is set in a curcuit, the charges still move randomly, but have a drift velocity around the curcuit. This is only in the order of about 0.1 mm/s.

The question is short and simple, and maybe the answer is too.

Why are collisions happening so much more frequently while drifting than when there is no current?

Turning a flashlight or an electrical heater on must gives a large increase in collision frequency to produce that much more energy than in the electrostatic case. Or what.

Comment: why do you think the collision frequency is changing? Think of an ideal gas with the molecules zipping around with a high collision frequency.  If you turn on a fan, the gas flow rate is still much smaller than the molecular velocity, and the collision rate really doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collision frequency of electrons in a metal at room temperature is given by the thermal distribution of the electron velocities (please note that this is already a somewhat questionable approximation, metals really require a quantum mechanical treatment). I do not believe that this collision frequency increases much when a current flows trough the metal. What does happen, though, is that on average there is no energy transfer between the electrons and the lattice if there is no drift, because the electrons are in thermodynamic equilibrium with the lattice. When we add an electric field electrons accelerate a little between any two collisions and then they are not in thermal equilibrium with the metal ions any longer. As a result they will shed their additional kinetic energy to the ions in these collisions
 which will heat the metal.