# Does a DC supplied superconductive coil gives off radiation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

A DC supplied superconductive electric coil must emit EM radiation according to Maxwell's law because rotation is acceleration

Comment: Yes because the electrons are moving in circles (a spiral path) and by this are accelerated.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler While the electrons are moving in circles their drift velocity is so small that I doubt that any measurable amount of radiation is emitted.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler You should convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does not a steady and divergence-less current distribution radiate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/468698/why-does-not-a-steady-and-divergence-less-current-distribution-radiate)

Comment: This study considers a uniform circular motion in a ring of radius α. Supposed that these math apply to a perfect cycle circuit, then does not apply to an ellipsoid electric coil or an irregular circuit.

Comment: OP changed this to superconducting wire. Sneaky!

Comment: To a moving observer the coil radiates plenty. Absolutely nothing and nobody needs to be accelerated to detect electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: @FlatterMann A natural phenomenon needn't observers to happen i.e. volcano explosion

Comment: @elias2010 If you read my comment again then you will find that I spoke about about a trivially observable effect (magnetic induction) and not about unobserved ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Energy can be stored via an electric current sent through a coil of superconducting wire. Once the coil is short-circuited (closed on itself), the current flows almost indefinitely without losses (an experiment has already been done for years for a ring) and produces an "eternal" magnetic field The energy is therefore stored in the coil in magnetic and electrical form and can then be retrieved in a very short time. Just like in an atom, there is also a rotational movement of the electrons, but there is no electromagnetic radiation because of the quantization of the energy ( we can consider a a coil ring as a linearized atom...). so if the system (coil) is used to store energy, there is no loss of energy in any form.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_magnetic_energy_storage

Comment: Therefore Maxwell's law is false needing revision.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't radiate because of curvature. It is like an earlier question about current in a straight wire where electrons are accelerating in the field with a Drude-relaxation time.

But of course even a resistor with unconnected terminals has thermal noise, will be radiating at finite temperatures.

Comment: So what is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation then?

Comment: @rghome That is radiation from the acceleration (change of direction) in bending magnets, wigglers, etc. A coil is not different from an ordinary wire.

But I see that you now changed your question to superconducting wire! So no Drude resistance. Sneaky!

Comment: I'm not the OP by-the-way. The comment was a genuine follow-up question, which I think you answered.

Comment: In the changed question the current is ever increasing with time. This completely changed the character of the question without this being consistently reflected in the body.

Answer (score -2):

Although the drift velocity of electrons inside a wire is only about 0.1 mm/s [(according to this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156233/drift-velocity-of-charges-in-current) there is a net flow of electrons through the wire.

Thats why the statement

> A DC supplied electric coil must give off EM radiation according to Maxwell's law because rotation is acceleration

is right. Any accelerated electron emits photons.

This could easily be demonstrated by the following experimental setup. Using a current carrying coil the Ohm resistance and the heat giving to the surrounding are higher compared with the straight wire from this coil.

Comment: Can you find a formula giving the wavelength(λ) as a function of amperage(I) and induction(L)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_magnetic_energy_storage