# Why does not a steady and divergence-less current distribution radiate?

Tags: electromagnetism

For example ,for a steady current loop,the charges are all running in a circle,so they are all accelerating,won't accelerating charges emit radiation?Another example is steady current torus which has non-uniform cross section diameter at different places,in this case,the charges will not only have angular acceleration ,but also have linear acceleration.
The only explanation is that although each charge will radiate ,but if you sum all the radiation together,it is zero for steady and divergence-less current distribution,is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructive interference between the radiation fields of the large number of electrons making up the steady current results in no radiation.

Another way to see this is that all the multipole moments are constant.

The mathematical details can be found [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/463e/3ef7f89d34c7a1205f3481ff17ad2a54fd55.pdf).

Comment: This study considers a uniform circular motion in a ring of radius α. Supposed that these math apply to a perfect cycle circuit, then does not apply to an ellipsoid electric coil or an irregular circuit.